# How to use GetFiles() search to include doc files but excude docx files?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, filesystems

Currently I am looping through my file system like this

```
For Each filename As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.doc")
```

However this is including docx files to the list of files that GetFiles returns. I wish to only search for doc files and not docx. Any idea if there is a truncate or stop search character I can use in the search pattern?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.doc",
                                         System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(Function(q) q.EndsWith("x") = False).ToArray()`  if you used `DirectoryInfo` you could filter the actual extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `GetFiles`, you can use LINQ to do further filtering.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test", "*.doc")
             .Where(file=> file.EndsWith(".doc", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
             .ToArray();//If you want an array back
```

[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a searchPattern such
>   as "*.txt", the number of characters in the specified extension
>   affects the search as follows:
>
> - If the specified extension is **exactly three characters long**, the    method returns files with extensions that begin with the specified extension. For example, "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" and  "book.xlsx".

Comment: It worked but can you explain what the StringComparison argument is doing?

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's unfortunate there's no cleaner way to do this, but it really appears that there is not.

Comment: @codemonkeyliketab, Sure, the later comparison is performed on string values, now you could end up with an extension as `DOC` or `doc` (different case), `StringComparison` parameter is doing the comparison with ignoring case so `DOC` and `doc` would be considered same

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that you want to iterate over your files and considering the default behavior of these methods I suggest to use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles. In this way you could add a simple check on the extension of the current file

```
foreach(string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, "*.doc"))
{
   if(!filename.EndsWith("x", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
   {
      .....
   }
}
```

Not elegant as the Linq only solution but still working and not creating an array of all the filenames present in the directory

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C# programmer so may be there can be syntax mistake, but i think it may solve your problem.

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.doc")
    .Where(fi => string.Compare(".doc", fi.Extension,  
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
{
 myFiles.Add(fi);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `string.Compare(".doc", fi.Extension,  
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0` `String.Equals` could be used, which also takes a parameter to do case insensitive comparison. `String.Compare` is mostly used to determine the ordering of strings.